# TCP Client / Server packet loss

Tags: node.js

I'm currently developing a TCP Client and Server in NodeJS.
But why do I have a "packet loss" here?
Look at the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WseEO.png

Client Code:

```
console.log('Starting Client...')

var net = require('net')

var client = new net.Socket()

client.connect(3000, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('Connected to server on 127.0.0.1:3000')

    var packet
    for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
        packet = new Buffer(4)
        packet.writeUInt32LE(i, 0)
        client.write(packet)

        console.log('Packet Counter sent: ' + i)
    }
})

client.on('error', function(e) {
    if(e.code == 'ECONNRESET') {
        console.error('Connection abnormally closed')
    } else if(e.code == 'ECONNREFUSED') {
        console.error('Connection refused. Server down?')
    } else {
        console.error('Unhandled error occured:')
        console.error(e)
    }
})

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed')
})
```

Server Code:

```
console.log('Starting Server...')

var net = require('net')

var server = net.createServer(function(session) {
    console.log('Connection opened')

    session.on('data', function(packet) {
        var packet_counter = packet.readUInt32LE(0)

        console.log('Packet Counter received: ' + packet_counter)
    })

    session.on('error', function(e) {
        if(e.code == 'ECONNRESET') {
            console.log('Connection closed')
        } else {
            console.error('Unhandled session error occured:')
            console.error(e)
        }
    })

    session.on('end', function() {
        console.log('Connection closed')
    })
})

server.on('error', function(e) {
    if(e.code == 'EADDRINUSE') {
        console.error('Port 3000 already in use')
    } else {
        console.error('Unhandled server error occured:')
        console.error(e)
    }
})

server.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0')

console.log('Server started on 0.0.0.0:3000')
```

How to resolve this issue and get the expected output in the Server log?

```
Packet Counter received: 0
Packet Counter received: 1
Packet Counter received: 2
Packet Counter received: 3
Packet Counter received: 4
Packet Counter received: 5
Packet Counter received: 6
Packet Counter received: 7
Packet Counter received: 8
Packet Counter received: 9
Packet Counter received: 10
Packet Counter received: 11
Packet Counter received: 12
Packet Counter received: 13
Packet Counter received: 14
Packet Counter received: 15
Packet Counter received: 16
Packet Counter received: 17
Packet Counter received: 18
Packet Counter received: 19
Packet Counter received: 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably no packet loss. TCP just doesn't send packets like how you expect. It sends a stream - like a file. A file isn't made of packets, it's made of bytes. TCP emulates this behavior. So when you send two "packets" the TCP layer (either your TCP library, or the OS or your router or your ISP) may combine them into one TCP packet or break them into multiple TCP packets.

To really know if there's packet loss you have to check the total size of received data vs the total size of sent data.

It is this file-stream-like behavior that is the reason people create higher layer protocols such as HTTP or FTP or Bittorrent - to encode where a packet start and end.

TCP doesn't do it for you.

Comment: So how can I split those combined packets?

Comment: That's left up to you. HTTP uses two newlines `"\n\n"` to detect the end of a packet (actually header, the full length of the data section is sent in Content-length header as a sring). Bittorrent uses it's own data encoding called bencoding to define where data starts and end. The traditional way in a lot of protocols is for the first byte or int you send to specify the size of the packet. If you're sending fixed size packets (like ints) you may just keep reading until you have as many bytes as necessary to reconstruct you data (keeping previous incomplete reads in a temporary buffer).

Comment: Or you may choose to not re-invent the wheel and use a known working protocol such as HTTP.

Comment: Thank your for the hint! Using console.log(packet) actually showed that there are more data left: http://i.imgur.com/Ac0c3ZJ.png. Thanks again! :)

@slebetman: I'm using a binary protocol but it was causing this "packet loss". Actually I can fix it with this now.

Comment: @slebetman hinted at this, but I want to call out that TCP can split a packet up too, not just combine them as you're seeing. So the receiver needs to buffer the responses and wait to act until a whole packet has arrived. "Line delimited json" is one way to handle this.